Build template parameter dynamically
I need to extend a certain pipeline template, that is expecting a parameter like this:
  parameters:
    deploy_stages: 
    - DEV
    - PROD

Is it possible to dynamically build those template parameters based on env variables:
trigger:
  batch: true

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: templates
    type: git
    ref: refs/heads/master
    name: my-template

variables:
- group: deployment-branches

extends:
  template: my-template.yml@templates
  parameters:
    deploy_stages: $(deployment)

steps:
  - bash: |
      DEPLOY_STAGES=( $deployment-branches.DEV, deployment-branches.PROD)
      echo "those are the stages: $DEPLOY_STAGES"
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=deployment]$DEPLOY_STAGES"


Hi @stefan.stt, may I know if the answers below could solve your query in the current topic. Please also be noted that the output variables via script and variables from variable group are processed at runtime rather than compile time, as I notice another post of yours. Hope the information helps and cheers!

Using variables:
extends:
  template: my-template.yml@templates
  parameters:
    deploy_stages:
      - $(stageA)
      - $(stageB)

The above excerpt assumes variables $(stageA) and $(stageB) were declared or defined somewhere in the pipeline or via a variable group.
Using pipeline parameters:
# my-pipeline.yaml

parameters:
  - name: stages
    displayName: 'Stages to deploy'
    type: object
    default:
      - DEV
      - PROD
    
  # ...

  extends:
    template: my-template.yml@templates
    parameters:
      deploy_stages: ${{ parameters.stages }}

In this scenario, you could directly set the deploy_stages from pipeline parameter stages.

I found out this option. But in my case it is best those parameters to be calculated based on variables e.g if variable.value = build branch -> add Dev to deploy stages

Based on the description, the requirement is to generate deployment value in script as an output variable to be used in downstream stage for deployment. For this, you should Set output variable in script and include template with the output variable value as the parameter rather than to extend the template.
Here is a sample YAML pipeline for your reference.
main.yml
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: templates
    type: git
    ref: refs/heads/master
    name: my-template

stages:
- stage: Stage_OutputEnvVar
  jobs:
  - job: Job_OutputEnvVar
    steps:
    - bash: |
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=deployment;isOutput=true]PROD"
      name: Step_OutputEnvVar

- template: my-template.yml@templates
  parameters:
    deploy_stages: $[stageDependencies.Stage_OutputEnvVar.Job_OutputEnvVar.outputs['Step_OutputEnvVar.deployment']]


my-template.yml
parameters:
- name: deploy_stages
  default: ''

stages:
- stage: Stage_Deploy
  dependsOn: Stage_OutputEnvVar
  variables:
    EnvToDeploy: ${{ parameters.deploy_stages }}
  jobs:
  - job: Job_Deploy
    steps:
    - bash: |
        echo "Steps to deploy to $(EnvToDeploy)"


